# mousekeys is too slow in gnome3 fedora

Tags: gnome, gnome3, mouse, access-control

Today I had to use mousekeys feature and tried it but it  was very slow and unsusable, can I incerase the speed of my cursor while using mousekeys?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `xkbset` command can adjust the mousekeys speed. I use this setting:

```
xkbset ma 50 20 20 30 300
```

which accelerates fast enough to get across the screen in reasonable time, but also starts out slow enough that I can tap a key and get a single pixel movement. Play with the numbers until you find something you like.

To install `xkbset` do `sudo dnf install xkbset`.

Comment: i cudnot find any package xkbset in fedora, are you sure that its name is xkbset in fedora?

Comment: I found xkbset here http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/software/xkbset/ and it worked! thanks! :) the same numbers works good for me

Comment: I actually use Debian, but I assumed xkbset was universal since it's so small and without it there's no way (that I know of) to configure these options.

Comment: My wireless mouse batteries just died! And this post was useful for me again :)

Comment: xkbset is a package in Fedora. You can install it via `sudo dnf install xkbdset`.